# match keyboard input to enum type data [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

im doing a college project, it has to do with doing a program that manages orders of a pizzeria. So i have it all planned, but when it comes to doing it i missunderstand somethings. The first is that i need to ask the user for a ingredient, and in the program, the ingredients are a enum type data, so i need to match de keyboard input with that. I tried this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <sring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
    const int MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA=20;
typedef array<int, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA> TIngrediente;
//enum ingredientes {TOMATE,QUESO,NATA,CEBOLLA,POLLO,HUEVO,SALAMI,ANCHOA,BACON,GAMBA};
TIngrediente leer_ingrediente(){
    TIngrediente r;
    enum ingredientes {TOMATE,
        QUESO,
        NATA,
        CEBOLLA,
        POLLO,
        HUEVO,
        SALAMI,
        ANCHOA,
        BACON,
        GAMBA};

    char ingrediente;
    getline(cin,ingrediente);
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA-1;i++){
        string ingrediente[i]=tolower(ingrediente[p]);
    }

    if(ingrediente=="queso")

    else if(ingrediente=="nata")

    else if (ingrediente=="cebolla")

    else if (ingrediente=="pollo")

    else if (ingrediente=="huevo")

    else if (ingrediente=="salami")

    else if (ingrediente=="anchoa")

    else if(ingrediente=="bacon")

    else if (ingrediente=="gamba")



return r;
}
```

i dont know if i should declare `enum{}` as global, or just inside `leer_ingredientes()`

Another thing is that as i said i dont know what to do here (to match the input with the enum()) :

```
char ingrediente;
    getline(cin,ingrediente);
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA-1;i++){
        string ingrediente[i]=tolower(ingrediente[p]);
    }

    if(ingrediente=="queso")

    else if(ingrediente=="nata")

    else if (ingrediente=="cebolla")

    else if (ingrediente=="pollo")

    else if (ingrediente=="huevo")

    else if (ingrediente=="salami")

    else if (ingrediente=="anchoa")

    else if(ingrediente=="bacon")

    else if (ingrediente=="gamba")



return r;
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well good practice is to write a function to convert string to ingrediente.
which will look like below. Assuming that enums have basic type int with your platform

```
int strToIngrediente(const char *ingr)
{
  if(!strcmp(ingr, "queso"))
    return QUESO;

 if(!strcmp(ingr, "queso"))
    return QUESO;

 if(!strcmp(ingr, "nata"))
    return NATA;
.
.
.  
}
```